# Typescript - How to explicitly assign the type of each property when we know all of it is the same?

Tags: typescript, object

Let says I have the object

```
interface Name {
  first: string;
  middle: string;
  last: string;
  blah: string;
  blahblah: string;
}
```

As you can see, every one of property is string. Is there a way to not typing "string" so much time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Record` instead:

```
type Name  = Record<
  | 'first'
  | 'middle'
  | 'last'
  | 'blah'
  | 'blahblah', string>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=6&ssc=24&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAcghgW2lAvFAShAxgewE4AmAPAFBRQA+UA5AGYCWeAzsNWZTQvQQQDYRtyVarzgtBHagCNRACwnCZcWUvkAaKCzz0AdgHMAfEA)

Comment: Thanks. But can the first ' | ' be omitted?

Comment: @BAXMAY yea it can, it's just there to make each line look the same, TS is tolerant of that first `|` being present or not

Answer (score 1):

Titian's response is correct (as always!), just keep in mind you can use mapped types to achieve the same result:

```
type Name = {
  [property in 'first' | 'middle' | 'last' | 'blah' | 'blahblah']: string
};
```